# want data wrapped automatically to shorten pages we print

Tags: worksheet-function

we pull data into excel from a web source. It fills a column all the way to row 2000. In the shortest possible way I want to spilt the data so that it fills column B, C, D, E, etc so when printing we are printer fewer pages. I would rather not cut and paste.

Comment: Give some example data results now and what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, try out text to columns to split up your data into multiple columns. Article on how-to is in the link. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-Convert-Text-to-Columns-Wizard-30B14928-5550-41F5-97CA-7A3E9C363ED7

Comment: I think the problem is that there are many rows, not that the text in each cell is too long. Your solution does not reduce the number of rows in a printout.